# Is it possible to 'update' ADF pipeline property through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

I would like to update some of the parameters of an ADF pipeline (e.g. concurrency level) of lots of mappings. I am not able to find out any cmdlet to be able to do this through powershell. I know I can drop existing pipeline and create new one, but that will start reprocessing all the Ready slices for that pipelines active period, which I don't want. Because in that case it will involve calculating up to what point existing pipeline has processed slices. And then this is only temporary, at some stage again I am going to revert back settings. I just want pipelines to change one of its properties. Doing this manually through the UI is slow and tedious. I am guessing there is no way around this, but let me know if you know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use "New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline" for this Update scenario:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619358.aspx

Use with the -Force parameter to force it to proceed even if the message reads "... may overwrite the existing resource". 
Under the hood, it's the same HTTP PUT api call  used by Azure UX Portal. You can verify that with Fiddler.

The already executed slices won't be re-run unless you set their status back to PendingExecution.

This rule applies to LinkedService and Dataset as well but NOT the top level DataFactory resource. A New-AzureRmDataFactory will cause the service to delete the existing DF along with all its sub-resources and create a brand new one. So be careful from there.